# .NET sensitive data exposure vulnerability remediation

Tags: c#, .net, owasp

My .NET application has a vulnerability of exposing sensitive data after it went through a penetration test.  I'll use the following simple web-app to illustrate my question.

The app takes the value - "secret phrase" and submits it to the server.

[image]

According to the penetration test result it states:

***Impact***

*By exploiting some other security issue, an attacker could gain access to secret phrase answers from
the page response. For example, by leveraging the presence of systemic Cross-Site Scripting a persistent
payload could be delivered which could then be used to scrape these values from application responses.
This information could then be used to access user accounts and could potentially be used to perform
further attacks.*

***Evidence***

*The following HTTP request/response shows the security question answers being returned from the page*

[image]

[image]

***Remediation Advice***

*Mask or remove sensitive data such as secret answer in all responses before they are returned from the
server.*

My application already handle XSS prevention attack, I also force to use TLS so I'm somewhat confused by this recommendation:

*"remove sensitive data such as secret answer in all responses"*

Is this as simple as in my code behind, I make sure the text box value is set to empty after I'm done with all the logics?  If yes, is there a quicker way to do this such as through the Response object?

Comment: You should chat with whoever did the penetration test.

Comment: So what happened when you attempted your proposed fix?  Did it remove the secret from the response or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Https encrypts data.
If you have to use http then you want to use a public and private key encryption system.

So firstly the client makes a request to the server for a public key.
The client then encrypts the data with said public key.
The data cannot be decrypted without a private key that only the server has.

You'll need a get request handler on the server that returns a public key.
You'll also need a way to encrypt the data on the client with the public key.
And finally a function on the server that handles the post request and decrypts the data.

That is literally how https works though, so you're better off creating a secure connection between the client and server with https:
https://nodejs.org/api/https.html.
(that's assuming you're using a node server).

If you have https you don't need encryption but if you use http you do.

Comment: This is a great page with more info https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/. The origonal that I put in the post was the documentation not a specific example.